# Quick search in list vs dataframe for millions of records. Records are in the form of dict

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pymongo

I had my data stored in list and was searching like this:
`next((sub for sub in curr_data_arr if (sub == query_string)), None)`

However, it takes a long time for 2 million values. Hence, i am planning of storing the values in dataframe, set index and search if the value is present:

```
curr_data_df = pd.DataFrame(list(audit_collection.find({"source_name":default_attributes['source_name']}, project_keys)))
curr_data_df = curr_data_df.set_index(queryString)
audit_data = {}
            try:
                print(tuple(query_string.values))
                stark_audit_data = curr_data_df.loc(tuple(query_string.values))
            except Exception as e:
                pass
```

I hope using df and df.loc search will be much faster?

**EDIT**

Here's one element (from a comment below):

```json
{
  "asin_product_title": "title 1",
  "contextHelperUrls": "url1",
  "d_category": "d1",
  "landing_page_url": "l1",
  "query": "how is it?",
  "leftProductTitle": "l1",
  "rightProductTitle": "r1",
  "moderator": "kodaga",
  "source_name": "SPRSPQA",
  "type": "Audit",
  "status": "Unworked",
  "uploadTime": "2023-01-24T02:42:27.825918+0000",
  "batchId": "638eafff21657a1f04c1faf0_fvj61wj51uxggv9t67efp8p8q7gdiokj_24012023024227"
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of `curr_data_arr`, you probably don't need a DataFrame.

Comment: Don't know if is feasible for yo or not but tuples tend to execute the fastest. You could try copying to a tuple although that may itself take too long

Comment: curr_data_arr contains dictionaries. They are results from mongo collection

Comment: @mozway what would i need to do a fast lookup then?
set cant be used to store dictionaries. List search took 10 minutes for 2 million records

Comment: Can you give an explicit minimal example? Also I'm assuming here that you want to perform multiple searches.

Comment: Also don't know if this is frowned on  or indeed if possible for you but when I'm in same situation I tend to use faster languages such as c/c++. One program that took over 6 hours to run in python, took 10 mins in c++.

Comment: @mozway this is 1 element
```
{
        "asin_product_title" : "title 1",
        "contextHelperUrls" : "url1",
        "d_category" : "d1",
        "landing_page_url" : "l1",
        "query" : "how is it?",
        "leftProductTitle" : "l1",
        "rightProductTitle" : "r1",
        "moderator" : "kodaga",
        "source_name" : "SPRSPQA",
        "type" : "Audit",
        "status" : "Unworked",
        "uploadTime" : "2023-01-24T02:42:27.825918+0000",
        "batchId" : "638eafff21657a1f04c1faf0_fvj61wj51uxggv9t67efp8p8q7gdiokj_24012023024227"
}
```

Comment: @GalodoLeste we are using python only

Comment: Can you add this in the question? And what is query_string? Ideally make a fully reproducible example

Comment: Why can't you submit a query to the MongoDB server to search for the documents you want?